# Phonegap CertUtil: -importPFX command FAILED

Tags: phonegap-build, certutil

I keep getting a

### `COMPILE OUTPUT

CertUtil: -importPFX command FAILED: 0x80070002 (WIN32: 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
CertUtil: The system cannot find the file specified.

My "Personal"

CertUtil: -delstore command completed successfully.

When i try to build my app for windows on phonegap build.

Any Ideas what i'm doing wrong?`

Comment: I Have same problem! Help us